# Gym's MsPacman-v0 colors look off

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I'm trying to coordinate two systems; one that was already pre-trained on the MuJoCo MsPacman-v0 and another that only supports the gym version for training. With both systems working on the rgb image representations, the color palette discrepancy is problematic (Gym Output Left, Expected Right):

[image]

Is there a simple way to fix this (i.e. pixel mapping trick or some environment setting I'm not aware of), or is there something more involved that I have to do? Of note, the actual simulation I'm running uses gym.

Answer (score 0):

Heyo, sorry about that! Look's like I'm dumb.

Context; I was trying to incorporate the [SPACE detection model](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.02407) into [DreamerV2](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.02193), and I didn't see the little footnote with Space:

> For some reason we were using BGR images for our Atari dataset and our
> pretrained models can only handle that. Please convert the images to
> BGR if you are to test your own Atari images with the provided
> pretrained models.

So yeah... if you see something like this, I guess this is what's wrong...